# Flatten a dictionary of dictionaries of lists of other dictionaries of lists of

Tags: python, dictionary

I have this highly nested dictionary tree:

```
sample = {"name": "one",
          "id": "1",
          "children": [{"name": "two",
                        "id": "2",
                        "children": [{"name": "six",
                                      "id": "6",
                                      "children": []}, 
                                     {"name": "seven",
                                      "id": "7",
                                      "children": []}]},
                       {"name": "three",
                        "id": "3",
                        "children": []},
                       {"name": "four",
                        "id": "4",
                        "children": []}, 
                       {"name": "five",
                        "id": "5",
                        "children": []}]}
```

This is just an example in reality there are 7 or 8 levels of lists of children... Also every name and id are unique.

My goal is to flatten this tree into a dictionary that has the value of all name keys as keys and their ids as second key-value pair:

```
sample = {"one": {"id":"1"},
          "two": {"id":"2"},
          "three": {"id": "3"}, ...}
```

Actually there are more key-value pairs but I am only interested in the names and their associated ids.

I tried to wrap my head about it but my skills in recursions aren't very good, had a hard time, so I ask you for help. Also I searched for similar problems, but the fact that the dicts are encapsulated in lists makes it not really comparable, for me anyway...

I came up with a solution to solve my problem but it was the hackiest and ugliest code I every wrote, and I am ashamed of it. Basically I transformed the dict into its string representation and used regex to find my pairs! And this is bad but I had to prototype something to have time to take care of other problems...

So any ideas, guys?

Comment: Why not just `{"one": "1", "two": "2", ...}`?

Comment: @tobias_k this is also a possible output possible. But I can't change the input tree, this is given and makes me headaches.

Comment: Note that you could have duplicate keys that rewrite the data, so you'd either have to check for this before hand or else ensure this is not the case via the original encoding method. For example, the children is a list of dictionaries, so there is nothing to ensure the keys are unique

Comment: @Alexander all names and ids are unique. It is a dict representation of a tree.

Answer (score 3):

You can make a recursive function like this (assuming that each of the dicts is properly structured):

```
def flatten(source, target):
    target[source["name"]] = {"id": source["id"]}
    for child in source["children"]:
        flatten(child, target)
```

Sample:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> flatten(sample, d)
>>> d
{'seven': {'id': '7'}, 'six': {'id': '6'}, 'three': {'id': '3'}, 'two': {'id': '2'}, 'four': {'id': '4'}, 'five': {'id': '5'}, 'one': {'id': '1'}}
```

Or like this, if you do not like passing the target dict as a parameter:

```
def flatten(source):
    d = {source["name"]: {"id": source["id"]}}
    for child in source["children"]:
        d.update(flatten(child))
    return d
```

Sample:

```
>>> flatten(sample)
{'one': {'id': '1'}, 'four': {'id': '4'}, 'seven': {'id': '7'}, 'five': {'id': '5'}, 'six': {'id': '6'}, 'three': {'id': '3'}, 'two': {'id': '2'}}
```

You could also simplify the output to be a simple, non-nested dictionary:

```
def flatten(source):
    d = {source["name"]: source["id"]}
    for child in source["children"]:
        d.update(flatten(child))
    return d

>>> flatten(sample)
{'one': '1', 'four': '4', 'seven': '7', 'five': '5', 'six': '6', 'three': '3', 'two': '2'}
```

Comment: Hmm, I got a TypeError here:                                   TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-89eb07410402> in <module>()
      5 
      6 new = {}
----> 7 flatten(sample, new)
      8 new

<ipython-input-12-89eb07410402> in flatten(source, target)
      1 def flatten(source, target):
----> 2     target[source["name"]] = {"id": source["id"]}
      3     for child in source["children"]:
      4         flatten(child, target)
      5 

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: Python 3.4 Kernel on Ipython Notebook, this is the traceback: TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-89eb07410402> in <module>()
      5 
      6 new = {}
----> 7 flatten(sample, new)
      8 new

<ipython-input-12-89eb07410402> in flatten(source, target)
      1 def flatten(source, target):
----> 2     target[source["name"]] = {"id": source["id"]}
      3     for child in source["children"]:
      4         flatten(child, target)
      5 

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: It seems like the structure of your dictionary is different/more complex than in your example. In particular, there seem to be strings in the "children" list. You can add an `if isinstance(source, dict)` here and there, but that's difficult to tell without seeing your actual dictionary structure.

Comment: You're right, some indention error. It works, cool! And the code is so short and simple, I like it! Not that crap I coded to get it ;) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you data is actually more complex than your example:

```
def rec_get(d, k):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        if k in d:
            yield (d[k], {"id": d["id"]})
        for v in d.values():
            yield from rec_get(v, k)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for v in d:
            yield from rec_get(v, k)
print(dict(rec_get(sample ,"name")))
```

Output:

```
{'five': {'id': '5'}, 'six': {'id': '6'}, 'four': {'id': '4'}, 'one': {'id': '1'}, 'three': {'id': '3'}, 'two': {'id': '2'}, 'seven': {'id': '7'}}
```

If you wanted a more general  function, you could so something like:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from collections import Iterable


def rec_get(d, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        yield from ((d[k], k) for k in kwargs.keys() & d)
        for v in d.values():
            yield from rec_get(v, **kwargs)
    elif isinstance(d, Iterable) and not isinstance(d, str):
        for v in d:
            yield from rec_get(v, **kwargs)
```

Which just as an example using your input and passing keywords arguments:

```
print(list(rec_get(sample, name="name", id="id")))
```

Outputs:

```
[('1', 'id'), ('one', 'name'), ('2', 'id'), ('two', 'name'), 
('6', 'id'), ('six', 'name'), ('7', 'id'), ('seven', 'name'), 
('3', 'id'), ('three', 'name'), ('4', 'id'), ('four', 'name'), ('5', 'id'), ('five', 'name')]
```

Comment: This looks interesting, yield from is something I have problems to get. However, it is interesting, with timeit, your solution is almost 10 times slower than the version from @tobias_k. Is `isinstance` so expensive?

Comment: @KleinerNull, it will work for a lot more nesting as it checks the whole dict, if you add some names and id's to the empty children list you will see what I mean.

Comment: Interesting, I will test it tomorrow with a real life example. Just out of couriosity, can I easily change this to also keep other dicts inside except the children list?

Comment: Yep, you can keep whatever you want, you would insert your logic where the  `if k in d:` is, this looks for a key. it does not care where it is

Comment: @KleinerNull, I added another example of how you could search for multiple keys at a time